# Do iPad / iPhone Apps Get Reviewed and Approved on weekends?

Tags: iphone, ipad

Do iPad / iPhone Apps Get Reviewed and Approved on weekends?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I uploaded several builds on weekends and my experience is that no build ever got reviewed on weekends. So I'm quite confident to say: Unfortunately **no**.

Comment: ? you link to the the exact question here.

Comment: Sorry about that, they are telling me Sundays apple review apps. http://www.quora.com/Do-iPad-iPhone-apps-get-reviewed-and-approved-on-weekends

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the answer you're looking for is "no".